# How to export database from brightway with ecosplod format?

Tags: brightway

What formats are available for exporting the database or project from brightway2? Is it possible to import it to openLCA?
Is it possible to export as ecospold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details about export and imports possibilities can be found in the documentation ([here](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/technical/bw2io.html)). As far as I know exporting to Ecospold is not yet an option but there are several alternatives for importing data.